# Special Price not changing in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, special-price

1.I m adding a **configurable product** in magento ,with some price 
and after adding sale tag over it for a particular duration it still shows up after the end of the date.
Price is showing different on the page where all products are listed and different when I open it.

2.Sale product price do not update to back to normal after sale ends.

Comment: try to edit in php file